# How to remove null value form multiple column in sql select statement result set

Tags: oracle11g, oracle10g

How to achieve the result set in sql query 
[image: How to achieve the result set in sql query t]

Comment: We need to see the query... but max and group by would seem to do it; provided there is a way to relate the rows to eachother.  However it is more likely you have a problem in your base query generating data this way.  Can we see the SQL used to get this?

Comment: this result set is coming from multiple union query and every union query is giving separate column result set, so for remainging column is every union query i m adding null value as a column and then in the end i m getting result set like this.

Comment: So aside from order, how do the different unions relate?  is there a field they share? or can I assume that the order they come back in the union is the order they need to be linked?  the problem here is there isn't enough information to solve this unless we make lots of assumptions.

Comment: @user3068880 Please share the query you have tried to achieve than i can able to answer

Comment: select a1.col1,a1.col2,a1.col3,a1.col4 from 
(select 1 as col1 col2,null col3,null as col4 from table1 t1
where col2 = 'A1'
union
select 2 as col1, col2,null col3,null as col4 from table t1
where col2 = 'A1'
union 
select 3 as col1, col2, null col3,null as col4 form table t1
where col2 = 'A1')a1
union
select a2.col1,a2.col2,a2.col3,a2.col4 from 
(select null col1,null as col2,1 as col3 col4 from table1 t1
where col3 = 'A2'
union
select null col1,null as col2,2 as col3 col4 from table t1
where col3 = 'A2' 
union 
select null col1,null as col2,3 as col3 col4 form table t1
where col3 = 'A2')a2

Comment: query looks something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could work along

```
WITH
T1 AS (
  SELECT
    val,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NULL ORDER BY id) rn
  FROM Table1
),
T2 AS (
  SELECT
    val,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NULL ORDER BY id) rn
  FROM Table2
),
T3 AS (
  SELECT
    val,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NULL ORDER BY id) rn
  FROM Table3
)
SELECT
  T1.val column1
  , T2.val column2
  , T3.val column3
FROM T1
JOIN T2
  ON T1.rn = T2.rn
JOIN T3
  ON T2.rn = T3.rn
ORDER BY T1.rn
;
```

You'd need to

- put the statements, which are now going into the `UNION` into "T1" through "T3", and
- move your current sort orders to the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic functions respectively.

… and should be done: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e815b/2/0)

Please comment, if and as further detail is required.

Comment: hi Abecee this is the xact solution i was looking for..long back i have used this syntax and i forget about it..you have a saved my day..thanks a lot

Comment: I just hope the order in each table is correct. otherwise you'll be joining data incorrectly.

Comment: @xQbert: If the original subqueries do return the data in the correct order - why should this no longer work with the sort order moved to the analytic functions' sort order?

Comment: @abecee What orderby was applied to the original unions so that A1 was on row 1 and b1 was on row 1 and C1 was on row one?  none right? The since no order by was explicitly defined, each set may come back in a different order over time as new data is added and old data purged. This means over time A1 B2 and C3 may all occur on the same row in the future. This answer inherently relies on the order of the subqueries always being the same when returned as now.  Without an order by, ordered returned by the db engine is not guaranteed!

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/481f86/1/0 is what I'm getting at.. how do we KNOW that ID is what drives A1 going with A2 and A2 going with A3?  but since the answer is accepted moot point.

Comment: @xQbert: Right - with no details about the original query, we do not **know** the original sort criterion. Two options: Either there was none - than there is no (way for any) alignment to be preserved. Or the OP does know the criterion - and will be able to move it to the `ROW_NUMBER … ORDER BY …` Sure an aspect, one should keep in mind.